# configuring system properties for Jenkins service

Tags: jenkins, javadoc

#### Background

I have the following Jenkins config.

- Ubuntu machine
- Jenkins installed using `apt-get`, and is started as a service (`service jenkins start`).
- To this point I have not made any modifications to Jenkins config.

---

We have several Ant projects for which I want to publish Javadocs using Jenkins.

After configuring the [Javadoc plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Javadoc+Plugin), I quickly hit [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32619) where only the Javadoc frames are displaying, without any content.

Some reading ([here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) and [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy)) told me that I need to configure Jenkins' Content Security Policy, and that this is done by modifying system properties passed to Jenkins.

However, despite digging around I have not found clear docs on *how to pass these system properties to the Jenkins service*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question.

To set system properties for the Jenkins service:

#### Steps

1. Stop Jenkins (`service jenkins stop`). You will need root privileges.
2. Edit the `/etc/defaults/jenkins` file.
3. Add an additional line for the `JAVA_ARGS` that you want to pass.
4. `JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"your CSP configuration here\""`
5. Start Jenkins (`service jenkins start`).

#### Explanation

Look at `/etc/init.d/jenkins` for a line similar to:

```
NAME=jenkins
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME
```

These tell us that the Jenkins daemon will look for a file named /etc/default/jenkins. If present, it `.`s that file.

If you set `$JAVA_ARGS` in `/etc/default/jenkins` it will be substituted in the line below, located later in the `/etc/init.d/jenkins` file:

```
$SU -l $JENKINS_USER --shell=/bin/bash -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -- $JAVA $JAVA_ARGS -jar $JENKINS_WAR $JENKINS_ARGS" || return 2
```

#### Notes

1. Even after you do the above, the Javadoc may not load properly. Try doing a hard refresh (Ctrl-Shift-R on Chrome).
2. As detailed in (the Jenkins docs)[https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy] there is a temporary way to do this as well. Read that page and try to understand the implications well.
3. Changing the Content Security Policy has serious implications especially if your Jenkins is public. It's worth the effort to understand *just what policies* you are modifying.